# Find word in file, return definition

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm making a small dictionary application just to learn Python. I have the function for adding words done (just need to add a check to prevent duplicates) but I'm trying to create the function for looking words up.

This is what my text files looks like when I append the words to the text file.

```
{word|Definition}
```

And I can check if the word exists by doing this,

```
if word in open("words/text.txt").read():
```

But how do I get the definition? I assume I need to use regex (which is why I split it up and placed it inside curly braces), I just have no idea how.

Comment: This might be a little more complex than you were looking for but this is a task that would be best handled using a xml database.

Comment: @kylek It would indeed be better suited to use an XML database or something alike. But the point at the moment is to learn the syntax, when I get better I might redo this using an XML DB. Who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` would read the entire file contents. You could do this instead:

```
for line in open("words/text.txt", 'r').readlines():
    split_lines = line.strip('{}').split('|')
    if word == split_lines[0]: #Or word in line would look for word anywhere in the line
        return split_lines[1]
```

Comment: Great answer, easy for a newbie like me to understand. The ending curly brace is not stripped but using this line.strip()[1:-1] it removes both. But since each entry is on a new line and it reads line-by-line there is no need for the curly braces. If I type in a word that doesn't exist it returns "None", where does this come from? Does Python itself return that?

Comment: Oh  at the end of the for loop if nothing is explicitly returned python takes that as a None  .

Comment: To get the `strip` to work, remember that `readlines()` includes the new line character also at the end of the line. So you should include that in the characters to be removed: `strip('{}\n')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary if you want effective search.

```
with open("words/text.txt") as fr:
    dictionary = dict(line.strip()[1:-1].split('|') for line in fr)
print(dictionary.get(word))
```

Also try to avoid syntax like below:

```
if word in open("words/text.txt").read().
```

Use context manager (`with` syntax) to ensure that file will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

To get all definitions

```
f = open("words/text.txt")
for line in f:
  print f.split('|')[1]
```

Comment: If the curly braces are part of the file you will want to remove those as well.